# In a Linux system without X started, how do I assign the right windows key to the right control key?

Tags: linux, keyboard, console, keyboard-layout

I am working on a Linux system without X server, so I don't have Xmodmap to change keys on my keyboard. Since the keyboard attached to the Linux PC is a "windows keyboard" (if there is such a thing) with a "windows key" and the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is unhandy to reach, I want to use the windows key for the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  key.

So this is what I do:

```
echo keycode 126 = CtrlR     | loadkeys -
```

I determined the number 126 with `showkey`.

yet, it doesn't seem to change anything with regards to the behavior of the right windows key.

I am a bit surprised because I was able to switch the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Capslock</kbd>  keys with a similar

```
echo keycode   1 = Caps_Lock | loadkeys -  
echo keycode  58 = Escape    | loadkeys -
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do this with [`loadkeys`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/loadkeys), which requires that you have a keyboard configuration file (which you can get a starting point using [`dumpkeys`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dumpkeys)).

The hard part, of course, is determining the relationship between the key names in X versus those in the console.

Further reading:

- [keymaps - keyboard table descriptions for loadkeys and dumpkeys](http://linux.die.net/man/5/keymaps)
- [Re: use the "windows" key as the escape key](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2009-12/msg00144.html)
- [How to change console keymap in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux)
- [7.6. Configuring the Linux Console](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.2/chapter07/console.html)  (Linux From Scratch - Version 6.2 )
- [Keyboard configuration in console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console) (Arch Wiki)
- [Extra keyboard keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys) (Arch Wiki)
  gives some hints toward determining what your keyboard uses for *Windows* key, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The modifiers `CtrlL` and `CtrlR` are different columns in the 
keymap to the usual modifier for generating `Control-a` and so on.
You probably intend to use `Control` for both left and right control keys, so try

```
echo keycode 126 = Control     | loadkeys -
```